# Starting out with a flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

Can anybody give me a hand with the following flowchart?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
   arr/.style = {-Triangle,very thick},
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick,
                 minimum height=9mm, minimum width=17mm,
                 fill=white, drop shadow},
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {Task};
\node (n2) [box, below right=of n1] {Representation};
\node (n3) [box, above right=of n2] {Skils};
\node (n4) [box, below  left=of n2] {Difficulty};
\node (n5) [box, right=of n2] {Solution};
%
\draw[arr]   (n1) -| ([xshift=-3mm] n2.north);
\draw[arr]   (n3) -| ([xshift= 3mm] n2.north);
\draw[arr]   (n4) -| (n2);
\draw[arr]   (n2) -- (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm going to ask you the same thing I did when you posted the [same question yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679265/starting-out-with-a-flow-chart#comment1685696_679265): What are you having problems with? Your code example doesn't appear to have anything to do with your picture. What kind of text is to be expected in the nodes? Do they all need to be the same size as they appear above? Do other edges need a number to? [It is certainly possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx9rc.png)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Te problem is that it does not fit within the page. I am using amsart and it just does not work

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The text is not a problem since it is easy to customize.

Comment: If the problem is that the diagram does not fit the page, you should actually show in your MWE how large the text area on your pages is. You used the `standalone` class which can have any size the diagram has. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It is possible, indeed!!!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two things you can do to get your flowchart to fit in the page:

1. Scale by adding options `scale=<percent>, transform shape` to the `tikzpicture`. This will only help some; eventually you'll need to...
2. Reorganize your flowchart nodes so they fit.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    bigbox/.style={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm},
    smallbox/.style={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm},
    bigcircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2cm},
    bigellipse/.style={draw, ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm},
    place/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
    fork/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction, lineto code={
        \draw[rounded corners, ->](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)-|($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.5!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)|-(\tikzinputsegmentlast);}
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape, node distance=1cm, >=Latex]
  \node(A)[bigbox]{Text A};
  \node(B)[bigbox, right=of A]{Text B};
  \node[place](X)[right=3cm of B]{};
  \node(C)[smallbox, above=2.5mm of X]{Text C};
  \node(D)[smallbox, above=5mm of C]{Text D};
  \node(E)[smallbox, below=2.5mm of X]{Text E};
  \node(F)[smallbox, below=5mm of E]{Text F};
  \node(G)[bigbox, above=of D]{Text G};
  \node(H)[bigbox, right=of C]{Text H};
  \node(I)[bigbox, below=of H]{Text I};
  \node(J)[bigbox, below=of I]{Text J};
  \node(K)[bigcircle, below=of J]{Text K};
  \node(L)[bigbox, left=of K]{Text L};
  \node[place](Y)[left=3cm of L]{};
  \node(M)[bigbox, above=2.5mm of Y]{Text M};
  \node(N)[bigbox, below=2.5mm of Y]{Text N};
  \node(O)[bigellipse, left=3cm of Y]{Text O};
  \draw[->](A)--(B);
  \draw[fork](B.east)--(D.west);
  \draw[fork](B.east)--(C.west);
  \draw[fork](B.east)--(E.west);
  \draw[fork](B.east)--(F.west);
  \draw[->](D)--(G);
  \draw[->](C)--(H);
  \draw[->](H)--(I);
  \draw[->](I)--(J);
  \draw[->](J)--(K);
  \draw[->](K)--(L);
  \draw[fork](L.west)--(M.east);
  \draw[fork](L.west)--(N.east);
  \draw[fork](M.west)--(O.east);
  \draw[fork](N.west)--(O.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks fantastic! Is it possible to switch it to a 'standalone' class??

Comment: @Jeff: Why would you use `standalone`? In your comments you wrote that you wanted `amsart`.

Comment: Just in case. But I'm using it the way you coded it! Thanks very much. You're next level!

Answer (score 2):

The "trick" is to use e.g. class article instead of standalone. Here is how your drawing fits into such a "standard page", where nothing else changes besides indenting your code:

[image: result]

```
%\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}

\begin{document}
 Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, “and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
           arr/.style = {-Triangle,very thick},
           box/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick,
                         minimum height=9mm, minimum width=17mm,
                         fill=white, drop shadow},
                                ]
        \node (n1) [box] {Task};
        \node (n2) [box, below right=of n1] {Representation};
        \node (n3) [box, above right=of n2] {Skils};
        \node (n4) [box, below  left=of n2] {Difficulty};
        \node (n5) [box, right=of n2] {Solution};
        %
        \draw[arr]   (n1) -| ([xshift=-3mm] n2.north);
        \draw[arr]   (n3) -| ([xshift= 3mm] n2.north);
        \draw[arr]   (n4) -| (n2);
        \draw[arr]   (n2) -- (n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just by moving around the lines

```
\tikzset{continue chain=going …}
```

you can have the chain of nodes turn at different points.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, chains, ext.paths.ortho, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter\tl_replace_once:Nnn\tikz@do@matrix@cont{\tikz@node@finish}{\tikz@alias\tikz@node@finish}\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff
\tikzset{tight matrix/.style={every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
  arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=.75]}, very thick},
  arr*/.style= {arr, rounded corners},
  box/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick, rounded corners=3pt,
                minimum height=9mm, minimum width=17mm},
  boxie/.style={box, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=14mm},
  ell/.style = {box, shape=ellipse},
  start chain=ch going right,
  every join/.append style=arr,
  marker/.style={node font=\small, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=8pt}
]
\node[box, on chain]       (n1) {Task};
\node[box, on chain, join] (n2) {Representation};
\matrix[node distance=1.5cm, on chain=ch, tight matrix]{
  \tikzset{start chain=m going below, node distance=3mm}
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 4} \node[boxie, on chain]{};
\\};
\foreach[count=\i]\t in {4, 3, 2, 1}
  \path (n2) edge[arr*, horizontal vertical horizontal,
                  ortho/distance={\i==2||\i==3?4mm:3mm},
                  "$\t\,\%$" {left, marker, at end}] (m-\i);
\scoped[start chain=x going above]
  \chainin (m-begin) node[box, on chain, join] (top) {Hat};
\chainin (m-2);
\node[box, on chain, join] {Pi};

\tikzset{continue chain=going below}                           % ← turn down!
\node[box, on chain, join] {Pa};
\node[box, on chain, join] {Po};
\node[ell, on chain, join] {Ellie};

\tikzset{continue chain=going left}                            % ← turn left!
\node[box, on chain, join] (ta) {Turn};

\matrix[node distance=1.5cm, on chain=ch, tight matrix]{
  \tikzset{start chain=m going below, node distance=3mm}
  \foreach \i in {1, 2} \node[box, on chain]{};
\\};
\node[node distance=1.5cm, ell, on chain] {};
\foreach[count=\i]\t/\u in {A/C, B/D}
  \path[arr*, horizontal vertical horizontal]
      (ta) edge["$\t$" {right, marker, at end  }] (m-\i)
    (m-\i) edge["$\u$" {left,  marker, at start}] (ch-end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]